# writing JavaScript for different clients

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically, my question is about managing/writing client side (javascript) for multiple business rules which differ across multiple clients.

Lets say, for example, that I have `config.js` where I have one flag that decide I need to perform logic for `client A` or `Client B`

**Config.js**

```
TestBoolFlag = true;
```

In Angular controller, I am injecting data from config.js and then using if else to decide i need to perform logic for client A or for Client B

**Angular controller**

```
var total = 500;

if (TestBoolFlag) {
    var discount = total / 1000 *100;
} else {
    var discount = total / 10 *10;
}
```

I am just giving basic example of my problem.

This way I am managing so many flags and so many if else statements.

Is there any better way writing javascript code for multi clients need?
Like, get rid of this flag, divide if else into two javascript files and inject one of them depending on client? etc

Can someone please suggest

Comment: In your specific example, you'd probably be best off having a separate `Client` object with a `discount` property (or a `calculateDiscount( )` function). For each client, you'd have a separate object in a separate file, and load only the one you need

Comment: Just to be clear, by "client" do you mean 'user' (e.g. bob vs. jim), or do you mean 'medium' (e.g. web vs. mobile)?

Comment: @Paul, i mean bob vs. jim

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use a database here to save client specific configurations and not hard-code it into the source code.

This way you can easily scale to more clients.